# JQuery check/fill checkbox based on text value

Tags: html, jquery

I have a form (form 1) that fills a HTML table. When clicking a row on the table, it pops up a modal form (form 2) representing the information in the row. I know how to fill form 2 with text values from the html table rows, such as

```
$("#table").on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $("#form2textInput").val(($(this).find("#row_cell_value").text()));
```

However one of the column values is a "True" or "False", filled from a checkbox in form 1 - therefore, form 2 has a corresponding checkbox input. How would one check the box in form 2 based on text values received from the respective HTML table row?

Checkbox HTML input for form 2

```
<input type="checkbox" id="form2checkboxInput" class="custom-control-input">
```

Example of Table HTML row cell for the checkbox value that populates form 2

```
<td id="checkboxvalue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"> True </td>
```

Comment: you want to show the check box is ticked or note? true if ticked and false if it isnt?

Comment: Yes, True for ticked and False for unticked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
const columnValue = $(this).find("#checkboxvalue").text().trim();

$("#form2checkboxInput").prop("checked", columnValue === "True");
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Tried this and fiddled with it a bit but doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Kaal: When this code(mentioned in this ans) runs, does the checkbox is present in the DOM or the checkbox is added later in the DOM?

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle the checkbox is already present in the DOM

Comment: @Kaal: I get it, its because of the spaces added before and after " True " text. By adding trim() method will work for you. `const columnValue = $(this).find("#checkboxvalue").text().trim()`. And then `$("#form2checkboxInput").prop("checked", columnValue === "True")`

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle Yes, this works - thank you so much! I will upvote your comment and mark this answer

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle would this be similar but instead of propping a checkbox you are propping radio buttons? How would one prop radio buttons based on  the given text value? Lets say there is a list of three radio button options - how would you prop the correct radio button option from the text input?

Comment: @Kaal: Yes even for the radio button, you can add checked attribute(or properties) mentioned in this ans.